# How can I make a program to check if the array is in descending , ascending order or none of them?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

This code only lets user fill the array:
It is supposed to check whether is it in descending or ascending order, or maybe none of them, without using any sorting function. But it doesn't work properly,as it doesn't sort when it is neither ascending, nor descending

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int array[10];
    int i;
    int c;
    int d;

    printf("Enter the element of array:\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }



    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {

        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        if(array[i]<array[i+1])
        {
            c=1;
        }
        else if(array[i]>array[i+1])
        {
            d=1;
        }
    }

    if(c==1)
    {
        printf("ASCENDING");
    }
    else if(d==1)
    {
        printf("DESCENDING");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("NONE");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Loop over the array from 0 to N-2, check if the next element is greater or equal to the current one. If not, it is not sorted. Same for descending with the check for less or equal.

Comment: Ascending means `[i] <= [i+1]` for all i between 0 and last_index - 1. Descending is analogous but with `>=`.

Comment: You're doing the tests correctly in the loop, but you need a few changes before it'll work.  Firstly, you're not initializing `c` and `d` so they could contain anything.  In particular, if either happens to hold `1`, you've got a risk of this "false alerting".  Secondly it'll only take a single instance of elements in either order to set `c` or `d` to `1`.  So, initialize them first.  That decide what their initial value means, versus what `1` means.  Then either modify the logic in the loop or the final tests at the end to get the behavior you really want.

Comment: If you want the simple solution, make a copy of the array, `qsort` the copy ascending, then `memcmp` the original, `qsort` the copy descending, `memcmp` the original, otherwise it's neither.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ASND 0
#define DSND 1

int main ()
{
    int a[10];
    int i = 0;
    int order;


    printf("Enter the element of array:\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }

    for(i=1;i<10;i++){
        if(a[i-1] < a[i]) {
            order = ASND;
            break;
        }
        if(a[i-1] > a[i]) {
            order = DSND;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i==10) {
        printf("all elements are same\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(order == ASND) {
        for(i=1;i<10;i++) {
            if(a[i-1] > a[i]) {
                printf("no order\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        printf("ascending order\n");
        return 0;
   }

    for(i=1;i<10;i++) {
        if(a[i-1] < a[i]) {
            printf("no order\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("descending order\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have broken the ascending or descending rule you will need to break out of the loop so your not resetting the ascending or descending rule variables you have used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int array[10];
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;

    printf("Enter the element of array:\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }



    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {

        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        if(array[i]<array[i+1])
        {
            c=1;
        }
        else if(array[i]>array[i+1])
        {
            d=1;
        }

        // Run of same value
        else if (d==0 && c==0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Can't be both ascending and descending
        if (d == 1 && c == 1)
        {
            d = 0;
            c = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(c==1)
    {
        printf("ASCENDING");
    }
    else if(d==1)
    {
        printf("DESCENDING");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("NONE");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is quite simple and very readable. I think it can do the job well! Only in the need of one loop to check it, summing up a counter for ascending or descending, and checking after!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int a[10];
    int i = 0;
    int order;


    printf("Enter the element of array:\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    int ascendingCount=0;
    int descendingCount=0;
    int num1=a[0];
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
        if(a[i]>=num1){
            num1=a[i];
            ascendingCount++;
        }
        else if(a[i]<=num1){
            num1=a[i];
            descendingCount++;
        }

    }
    if(ascendingCount==9) printf("it is ascendingCount");
    else if(descendingCount==9) printf("it is descending");
    else printf("its nothing");


    return 0;
}
```